# NoSuchElementException: None.get em play framework para scala

Tags: scala, crud, play-framework

Criei o método upadte, mas quando eu testo mostra o erro NoSuchElementException: None.get

```
UserController

   object UserController extends Controller {

   def update(id:Long) = DBAction {  implicit rs =>

   var user = simpleUserForm.bindFromRequest.get

   user.id = Users.toOption(id)
   Users.update(user)
   Redirect(routes.UserController.list)
  }

   val simpleUserForm :Form[User] = Form {
    mapping(
     "firstName" -> nonEmptyText,
     "lastName" -> nonEmptyText,
     "email" -> email,
     "birthDate" -> nonEmptyText,
     "phone" -> nonEmptyText,
     "username" -> text,
     "password" -> nonEmptyText
   )(UserForm.fromSimpleForm)(UserForm.toSimpleForm)
  }

}
```

edit.scala.html

```
@import models.auth.Users
@(title: String, user:models.auth.User)

@main(title){

<form method="post" action="@controllers.auth.routes.UserController.update(Users.toLong(user.id))">
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" value="@user.firstName"/><br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" value="@user.lastName"/><br/>
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="@user.email" /><br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" value="@user.phone" /><br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Birthdate(dd/MM/yyyy)" name="birthDate" value="@user.birthDate" /><br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="@user.username" /><br/>

<input type="submit" value="Update User" />
```

}

routes

```
 POST        /user/:id/         controllers.auth.UserController.update(id:Long)
```

Eu já fiz o create, read e delete, mas por update eu encontrei o erro nessa linha

var user = simpleUserForm.bindFromRequest.get

the error is NoSuchElementException: None.get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já deve ter resolvido este problema, acredito eu, mas de qualquer forma está claro que o seu bindFromRequest está vazio, o que ocasiona o None.

Na hora de fazer o .get você não verifica se o bindFromRequest tem ou não valor, o que pode ocasionar em None.get ao invés de Some.get